# Seeking example or docs for geotk-client-csw package

Tags: java, csw, client

I need a simple but fast CSW client. `CatalogServicesClient` is created terribly slow. I was about to write my own pool but suddenly found `org.geotoolkit.csw.CSWClientFactory` not mentioned in anywhere. It has `open()` with sematics that makes no sense to me.

Any directions please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Diving into the lib source code gives the following solution.

Prepare factory and params (cache into fields assumably):

```
CSWClientFactory cswClientFactory = new CSWClientFactory();
ParameterValueGroup clientFactoryParams = CSWClientFactory.PARAMETERS.createValue();
clientFactoryParams.parameter(AbstractClientFactory.URL.getName().getCode()).setValue(new URL(serviceURL));
```

Obtain the client when you need it:

```
CatalogServicesClient catalogServicesClient = (CatalogServicesClient) cswClientFactory.open(clientFactoryParams);
```

Subsequent calls are blazingly fast!