# Use GeoNetwork CSW from Java

Tags: references, geonetwork, csw, client

I want to use GeoNetwork CSW HTTP services from a full Java stack client, and not web client, mainly to use HTTP transactional service.

I'm always redirected on the login HTML page after making a post login request with the proper credential. I receive session id cookies correctly, and I provide it to next level transactional POST request, but I always receive the login HTML page as answer.

My use case is to fill up the CSW catalog in a programmatic way, and not using the web sheet.

Does any tutorial exist on that way of working with GeoNetwork CSW?

Comment: Perhaps https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/225645/could-anyone-provide-me-with-a-sane-example-or-docs-for-geotk-client-csw-package (http://www.geotoolkit.org/modules/clients/geotk-client-csw/) might help. I don't know of any tutorials.

Answer (score 2):

Recently, I feel, I had a similar problem, connecting to the GeoNetwork q-interface. The question is posted [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/231775/accessing-geonetwork-api-by-jsessionid-cookie).

Maybe it helps to review this and [my own answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/232346/44978) about my findings.

My problem was, that GeoNetwork does a couple of redirects when calling the authorization endpoint. Somehow, I wasn't following them correctly.

After all, I ended up calling  http://localhost:8080/geonetwork/srv/eng/catalog.signin to receive a session id, which I can use in turn to access the private datasets.

However, I still use credentials in every request (which are validated against the mentioned endpoint) but the session id should be valid too.

I now also use this in a setting to call GeoNetwork CSW endpoint.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use Java in order to implement a CSW client use the following library

> https://github.com/Geomatys/geotoolkit/tree/master/modules/clients/geotk-client-csw/src/main/java/org/geotoolkit/csw

A simple example of a CSW GetRecords request with a *CQL filter would be the following:

```
        /** The csw server. */
        private final CatalogServicesClient cswServer;
               ...
        log.info("[CSWClient] getRecords - Constructing request...");
               ...
        final GetRecordsRequest getRecords = cswServer.createGetRecords();

        // gmd:MD_Metadata or csw:Record
        getRecords.setTypeNames("gmd:MD_Metadata");

        // CQL_TEXT or FILTER
        getRecords.setConstraintLanguage("CQL_TEXT");

        getRecords.setConstraintLanguageVersion("1.1.0");

        getRecords.setElementSetName(ElementSetType.FULL);

        // OUTPUT FORMAT
        getRecords.setOutputFormat("application/xml");

        // OUTPUT SCHEMA
        // DC: http://www.opengis.net/cat/csw/2.0.2 or
        // ISO: http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd
        getRecords.setOutputSchema(os.value());

        // HITS or VALIDATE or RESULTS
        getRecords.setResultType(ResultType.RESULTS);

        getRecords.setMaxRecords(config.getMaxRecordsRequested());

        getRecords.setConstraint("<QUERY>");
```

*CQL is the Common Query Language